# jQuery tools tab - how can I stop the mouse event listener on the content area?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I think it is a simple question but I am not that used to jQuery.
The example at the bottom is exactly my problem.
When you click on the content area, jQuery fades to the next div, but I want to stop that behavior. I only want to switch the contents when I click on one of the arrow buttons.

But I think I don't even need jQuery Tools for that simple problem, but I am not that experienced in jQuery.

[Example](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/slideshow.html)

Greets 
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try unbinding the click event for the content.

use http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

you have to find the element the click event is registered on.